# Opening ArcMap in Maximized State in C#?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#

I am running windows 7 enterprise with ArcMap 10.2

l have an application that processes data, when the data is finished processing I have a button that will show the results in a datagrid.  From this datagrid form I have a button that will open ArcMap. This works fine, but only when ArcMap is maximized. If I open ArcMap from the button and its normal size, the layer will display in the table of contents, but not in the map control.

The same applies when I use the desktop automation sample from the SDK.

How can I solve this problem?

This code is from DesktopAutomation.cs from the developer kit.

```
// Copyright 2013 ESRI
// 
// All rights reserved under the copyright laws of the United States
// and applicable international laws, treaties, and conventions.
// 
// You may freely redistribute and use this sample code, with or
// without modification, provided you include the original copyright
// notice and use restrictions.
// 
// See the use restrictions at <your ArcGIS install location>/DeveloperKit10.2/userestrictions.txt.
// 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesFile;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;

namespace DesktopAutomationCS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private IApplication m_application;

        //Application removed event
        private IAppROTEvents_Event m_appROTEvent;
        private int m_appHWnd = 0;

    //Retrieve the hWnd of the active popup/modal dialog of an owner window
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int GetLastActivePopup(int hwndOwnder);

    public Form1()
    {
      ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
        InitializeComponent();

        //Preselect option
        cboApps.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void btnStartApp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            switch (cboApps.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                case "ArcMap":
                    doc = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.MxDocumentClass();
                    break;
                case "ArcScene":
                    doc = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcScene.SxDocumentClass();
                    break;
                case "ArcGlobe":
                    doc = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcGlobe.GMxDocumentClass();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch { } //Fail if you haven't installed the target application
        finally
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }

        if (doc != null)
        {
            //Advanced (AppROT event): Handle manual shutdown, comment out if not needed
            m_appROTEvent = new AppROTClass();
            m_appROTEvent.AppRemoved += new IAppROTEvents_AppRemovedEventHandler(m_appROTEvent_AppRemoved);

            //Get a reference of the application and make it visible
            m_application = doc.Parent;
            m_application.Visible = true;
            m_appHWnd = m_application.hWnd;

            //Enable/disable controls accordingly
            txtShapeFilePath.Enabled = true;
            btnShutdown.Enabled = true;
            btnDrive.Enabled = ShouldEnableAddLayer;
            cboApps.Enabled = btnStartApp.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            m_appROTEvent = null;
            m_application = null;

            txtShapeFilePath.Enabled = false;
            btnShutdown.Enabled = btnDrive.Enabled = false;
            cboApps.Enabled = btnStartApp.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void btnShutdown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_application != null)
        {
            //Try to close any modal dialogs by sending the Escape key
            //It doesn't handle the followings: 
            //- VBA is up and has a modal dialog
            //- Modal dialog doesn't close with the Escape key
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate(m_application.Caption);
            int nestModalHwnd = 0;
            while ((nestModalHwnd = GetLastActivePopup(m_application.hWnd)) != m_application.hWnd)
            {
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
            }

            //Manage document dirty flag - abandon changes
            IDocumentDirty2 docDirtyFlag = (IDocumentDirty2)m_application.Document;
            docDirtyFlag.SetClean();

            //Stop listening before exiting
            m_appROTEvent.AppRemoved -= new IAppROTEvents_AppRemovedEventHandler(m_appROTEvent_AppRemoved);
            m_appROTEvent = null;

            //Exit
            m_application.Shutdown();
            m_application = null;

            //Reset UI for next automation
            txtShapeFilePath.Enabled = false;
            btnShutdown.Enabled = btnDrive.Enabled = false;
            cboApps.Enabled = btnStartApp.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void btnDrive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        try
        {
            IObjectFactory objFactory = m_application as IObjectFactory;

            //Use reflection to get ClsID of ShapefileWorkspaceFactory
            Type shpWkspFactType = typeof(ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass);
            string typeClsID = shpWkspFactType.GUID.ToString("B");

            string shapeFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtShapeFilePath.Text);
            string fileFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(txtShapeFilePath.Text);
            IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)objFactory.Create(typeClsID);
            IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(fileFolder, 0); //(@"C:\data\test", 0);

            //Create the layer
            IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)objFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
            featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(shapeFile); // ("worldgrid");
            featureLayer.Name = featureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;

            //Add the layer to document
            IBasicDocument document = (IBasicDocument)m_application.Document;

            document.AddLayer(featureLayer);
            document.UpdateContents();
       }
        catch { } //Or make sure it is a valid shp file first

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    private void txtShapeFilePath_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnDrive.Enabled = ShouldEnableAddLayer;
    }

    private bool ShouldEnableAddLayer
    {
        get
        {
            //Only allow .shp file
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(txtShapeFilePath.Text))
            {
                return (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(txtShapeFilePath.Text).ToLower() == ".shp");
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    #region "Handle the case when the application is shutdown by user manually"
    void m_appROTEvent_AppRemoved(AppRef pApp)
    {
        //Application manually shuts down. Stop listening
        if (pApp.hWnd == m_appHWnd) //compare by hwnd
        {
            m_appROTEvent.AppRemoved -= new IAppROTEvents_AppRemovedEventHandler(m_appROTEvent_AppRemoved);
            m_appROTEvent = null;
            m_application = null;
            m_appHWnd = 0;

            //Reset UI has to be in the form UI thread of this application, 
            //not the AppROT thread;
            if (this.InvokeRequired) //i.e. not on the right thread
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new IAppROTEvents_AppRemovedEventHandler(AppRemovedResetUI), pApp);
            }
            else
            {
                AppRemovedResetUI(pApp); //call directly
            }
        }
    }

    void AppRemovedResetUI(AppRef pApp)
    {
        txtShapeFilePath.Enabled = false;
        btnShutdown.Enabled = btnDrive.Enabled = false;
        cboApps.Enabled = btnStartApp.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Clean up
        if (m_appROTEvent != null)
        {
            m_appROTEvent.AppRemoved -= new IAppROTEvents_AppRemovedEventHandler(m_appROTEvent_AppRemoved);
            m_appROTEvent = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

---

Code to open Arcmap in Maximized mode is below but it does not solve my problem. The code still acts the same i.e. loads in TOC but does not show the data

```
if (doc != null)
{
    //Advanced (AppROT event): Handle manual shutdown, comment out if not needed
    m_appROTEvent = new AppROTClass();
    m_appROTEvent.AppRemoved += new IAppROTEvents_AppRemovedEventHandler(m_appROTEvent_AppRemoved);

    //Get a reference of the application and make it visible
    m_application = doc.Parent;

    MaximizeApplicationWindow(m_application);

    m_application.Visible = true;
    m_appHWnd = m_application.hWnd;

    //Enable/disable controls accordingly
    txtShapeFilePath.Enabled = true;
    btnShutdown.Enabled = true;
    btnDrive.Enabled = ShouldEnableAddLayer;
    cboApps.Enabled = btnStartApp.Enabled = false;

public void MaximizeApplicationWindow(ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication application)
{
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IWindowPosition windowPos = application as ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IWindowPosition;
    windowPos.State = ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.esriWindowState.esriWSMaximize;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the IActiveView?

Comment: No, but probably because I *always* use ArcMap maximized. Do you have  any code to show associated with adding the datagrid to ArcMap? Like @Hornbydd said the refresh possibly isn't triggered but I can't see why WindowsState.Normal behaves differently in this respect to WindowsState.Maximized... now WindowsState.Minimized is a different story - calls to Refresh() are ignored as there's nothing to show in a minimized window. What graphics card do you have? (ATI or nVIDIA family)

Comment: Maybe in the maximized scenario, the ui actually opens normally, then gets a maximize message, which causes the refresh.  If you slightly resize the non-maximized window, does it refresh?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Actually when I use the code to open the UI the window doesn't refresh....  it just freezes.. if I stop the program, open Arcmap and maximize it, then manually close the Arcmap, Then if I open Arcmap with the program, because the window is maximized, it works.. data is displayed in the table of contents and in the data viewer

Comment: What does `IApplicationStatus.Initialized` return before you try to maximize? If not `true`, maybe try waiting until `IApplicationStatusEvents.Initialized` fires.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Hey Kirk  IApplicationStatus.Initialized returns True.  I have the same problem

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's going on.  Instead of using `new MxDocumentClass` to start arcmap.exe, you might try the more customary way ... using `ProcessStartInfo` with `ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized`, then `Process.Start`.  Then listen to `AppROTEvents.AppAdded` to get an `IApplication` reference.

Comment: I was going to try that, but I couldnt get a reference to the appliaction  Is there any code examples around?

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by @KirkKuykendall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167047/open-arcmap-in-maximized-state-in-c/335772#comment251930_167047):

> Instead of using `new MxDocumentClass` to start arcmap.exe, you might
>   try the more customary way ... using `ProcessStartInfo` with
>   `ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized`, then `Process.Start`.  Then listen to
>   `AppROTEvents.AppAdded` to get an `IApplication` reference.